# How can I update the system software DX100 controller - Yaskawa?

Tags: ros, driver, motoman, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please, can someone help me?

I'm trying to update the system software DX100 controller to DS3.32.00-14 or greater (-14) version.
I need to do it, because I would like to use the MotoROS app. I'm following the  [Motoman Driver](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Tutorials/indigo/InstallServer) Tutorial.

Thank you for the answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273076/how-can-i-update-the-system-software-dx100-controller---yaskawa?/) by [Matheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/31690/matheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-10-15**:
I don't think this is really a ROS question, it sounds like you should contact Motoman support directly for a firmware update to their controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @ahendrix already mentions, please contact your regional Yaskawa Motoman support about this. You can refer them to the tutorial, but it would probably be better to link to the [motoman_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver) page, specifically the [Requirements](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver#Requirements) section (note the DX100 specific information on that page).

That lists the *part number* your controller needs. Yaskawa should know what to do then.

If not, send us a message on the [ROS-Industrial mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0